# graphical component above the jxbrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I use `JxBrowser 6.2` on Windows. 
I try to add a swing component (a drop-down menu) above the browser view.

Even adding this component in the modal_layer, the component appears under the browser.

I use this code :

```
            JButton btn = new JButton("Hello");
            btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
            btn.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
            frame.getLayeredPane().add(btn, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following approach:

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
```

You can find more details about this approach at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013078-jmenubar